# Spring Security multirole based user

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have the project in which the dashboard functionality comes based on the role of the user and i am using spring security and hibernate for this.  but now the challenege is 1 user can have more than one role.  So i need to implement this in spring security as well.  so is there any way in spring to do this or i need to customize the spring security configuration.  Please suggust with code.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What metod are you using for recovering the user details? Are you using jdbc and default schema, or did you implemented a UserDetailsService?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use UserDetailsService to assign multiple roles to a particular user. Make two `entities User and UserRole(implements SimpleGrantedAuthority) and UserRole has the mapping of the User instance` i.e. the foreign key instance is on the UserRole table using `@ManyToOne with User`. Hence, a user can have multiple roles.

Answer (score 0):

The [RollerUserDetailsService](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/java/org/apache/roller/weblogger/ui/core/security/RollerUserDetailsService.java) and Spring [security.xml](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml) of my Apache Roller fork may be helpful for you.  I just have one role per user, but as Deepanjan mentioned you may just need to repeat the authorities.add(...) call in your UserDetailsService subclass.